# filter rows in df and return if between string values - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

The following returns a boolean on which integers are an increase on the previous row.

However, I'm hoping to incorporate filtering rows based off strings. Specifically, I want to return rows between `B` and `C`. So whenever `C` follows `B`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({                   
    'X' : ['A','B','C','D'],
    'Y' : [1.0,1.0,2.0,1.0],              
   })

df = df.assign(Z = df.Y.diff().gt(0))
```

Out:

```
     X      Y
0  1.0  False
1  1.0  False
2  2.0   True
3  1.0  False
```

But I want to do use string values to return rows when `C` follows `B`.

Intended Out:

```
   X    Y
1  B  3.0
2  C  2.0
```

Comment: What is the relationship between the two dataframes in your post?

Comment: None sorry. It's a little confusing. I'll change it

Comment: I would use `shift`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it what you want:

```
# current is B and next is C
s = df['X'].eq('B') & df['X'].shift(-1).eq('C')

# current row and the next row
df[s | s.shift()]
```